# is it possible to send mail with parentheses

Tags: linux, bash, email

`mail  -S from="(XXXXXX)  <root@xxxxx.yyyy.zzz>" -s "some text"   root < /dev/null`

after sending mail the from field is like `XXXXXX <root@xxxxx.yyyy.zzz`. How can i get this done?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got it :)

```
mail  -S from='"(XXXXXX)"  <root@xxxxx.yyyy.zzz>' -s "some text"   root < /dev/null
```

enclose the desired part in single quotes and the from part in single quotes.

Comment: ...the desired part in double quotes and the from part in single quote

Answer (score -1):

You have to quote the parenthesis:

```
mail  -S from="(\(XXXXXX\))  <root@xxxxx.yyyy.zzz>" -s "some text"   root < /dev/null
```

Received headers:

```
Date: Fri, 17 Apr 2020 12:51:54 +0100
From: "(XXXXXX)" <root@xxxxx.yyyy.zzz>
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. The result is: `\(XXXXXX\) <root@xxxxx.yyyy.zzz>`

Comment: Perhaps it depends on something, because as evident in the received headers the parenthesis are included.